# Android nv-websocket-client with SNI

Tags: android, ssl, websocket, sni

I am using android [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) library (both 2.0 and 1.31 versions) and I am trying to open a `wss:` connection; however, the connection fails with `503 Service not available` error message.

Upon investigating I found that HAProxy requires the clients to use the SNI extension, otherwise such error is returned regardless of the `Host:` header (I am using HAProxy as a loadbalancer).

Upon investigating further (with tcpdump/wireshark) I found that the client does not send SNI, a wrong certificate is returned (for a different domain), yet the client continues with the TLS connection and actually sends the HTTP request (as if no certificate checking was performed?).

My code is basically:

```
ws = new WebSocketFactory().createSocket(wsurl);
ws.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Config.getToken());
ws.addListener(this);
ws.connectAsynchronously();
```

I didn't find an easy way to set up the `SSLSocketFactory`, however it seems to me that the code in `nv-websocket-client` just uses the `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()`, which should be correct? `SSLCertificateSocketFactory` seems to be deprecated in favour of this approach.

Am I missing some key piece about SSL setup, is this and Android bug or is this and Android 'feature'?